# SQL Server trigger and run CLR method in a thread

Tags: sql-server-2008, asynchronous, redis, sqlclr

I want to log data changes to the redis db inside sql update trigger, calling by c# dll.
But I don't want to make any delay for trigger. As if logging redis operation works async.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: Use the tools the SQL Server provides for decoupling (such as service broker) rather than trying to do threading work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it uses PubSub but the concept is pretty much the same:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/frcogno/archive/2014/11/14/microsoft-sql-server-meets-redis-an-elegant-logging-platform-at-your-doorstep.aspx

Highlights in case the link goes:

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static void Publish(SqlString redisServerAddress, SqlInt32 redisServerPort, SqlString channel, SqlString message)
{
    using (RedisConnection rc = GetRedisConnection(redisServerAddress.Value, redisServerPort.Value))
    {
        rc.Publish(channel.Value, message.Value);
    }
}

CREATE PROCEDURE Redis.Publish(@RedisServerAddress NVARCHAR(1024), @RedisServerPort INT, @Channel NVARCHAR(1024), @Message NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS EXTERNAL NAME [MindFlavor.RESP.SQLCLR].    [MindFlavor.RESP.SQLCLR.Redis].Publish;
GO

EXEC [MindFlavor].[Redis].[Publish] N'ubuntu-spare.pelucchi.local', 6379, N'msbackup:sql', @txt;
```

Be mindful of the fact that in some environments (Azure for example), you'll need to mark your clr as `safe` which will throw up some issues if your dll or dependencies break clr `safe` practices.